# WordPress Plugin to create a React Public page on activation

Tags: php, reactjs, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

I'm building a WordPress plugin that creates an admin menu and stores the value in the WordPress backend and then shows this stored value on a Public page. But the code is not creating a Public page where I want to load a custom react page.

In the root directory, I have wp-react-kickoff.php file like this

```php
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Batmobile Design
 * Author: Batman
 * Author URI: 
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Description: WordPress React KickOff.
 * Text-Domain: wp-react-kickoff
 */

if( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) : exit(); endif; // No direct access allowed.

/**
* Define Plugins Contants
*/
define ( 'WPRK_PATH', trailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) );
define ( 'WPRK_URL', trailingslashit( plugins_url( '/', __FILE__ ) ) );

/**
 * Loading Necessary Scripts
 */
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'sd_scripts' );
function sd_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-react-kickoff', WPRK_URL . 'dist/bundle.js', [ 'jquery', 'wp-element' ], wp_rand(), true );
    wp_localize_script( 'wp-react-kickoff', 'appLocalizer', [
        'apiUrl' => home_url( '/wp-json' ),
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' ),
    ] );
}

require_once WPRK_PATH . 'classes/class-create-admin-menu.php';
require_once WPRK_PATH . 'classes/class-create-settings-routes.php';
require_once WPRK_PATH . 'classes/class-public-page.php';
```

Then I have created a folder called classes where I have

```php
class-create-admin-menu.php, 
class-create-settings-routes.php, 
class-public-page.php, 
wprk-public-page-template.php.
```

The code specific to create Public page looks like this

```
<?php
/**
 * This file will create Public Page
 */


function wprk_create_public_page() {
    $page = [
        'post_type' => 'Automatic page',
        'post_title' => 'WP React KickOff Public Page',
        'post_content' => 'asasasas',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1,
    ];
    $page_id = wp_insert_post( $page );
    update_post_meta( $page_id, '_wp_page_template', 'wprk-public-page-template.php' );
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'wprk_create_public_page' );
```

And my wprk-public-page-template.php

```php
<div id="wprk-public-app"></div>
<?php
wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-react-Kickoff', WPRK_URL . 'dist/bundle.js', [], wp_rand(), true );
wp_localize_script( 'wp-react-Kickoff', 'appLocalizer', [
        'apiUrl' => home_url( '/wp-json' ),
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' ),
    ] );
```

And In the ReactFolder, I have App.js, both Settings (This is for admin menu, it is working properly) and Public Page rendered like this

```js
import React from 'react';
import PublicPage from './components/PublicPage';
import Settings from './components/Settings';

function App() {
    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <Settings />
            <PublicPage />
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
export default App;
```

And for testing, let the Public page, look like this

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const apiUrl = appLocalizer.apiUrl;
const nonce = appLocalizer.nonce;



import React from 'react';

function PublicPage(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>hello world asasa</h1>
        </div>
    );
}

export default PublicPage;
```

I'm quite new to programming. Could someone help me identify why the Public page is not getting created?

Please let me know if you need additional information to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1):

your `post_type` argument in your create page function isnt valid.

If you have a custom post type you'll want to use the slug, otherwise, in your case if i understand correctly you want to create a standard wordpress page which the post type is `page`.

```
function wprk_create_public_page() {
    $page = [
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_title' => 'WP React KickOff Public Page',
        'post_content' => 'asasasas',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1,
    ];
    $page_id = wp_insert_post( $page );
    update_post_meta( $page_id, '_wp_page_template', 'wprk-public-page-template.php' );
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'wprk_create_public_page' );
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for responding. I want to create a custom wordpress page using React. This is like a custom React page with dashboard, graph etc

Comment: this is not working?

Comment: This worked. I have one more question : So this new page is currently created below admin settings page (only accessible to the admins). I want to create it as a Public page at a specific URL. How to achieve this.

Comment: I have created a new question for this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75203782/create-a-react-page-accessible-at-a-specific-url-on-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

The below code is Perfectly working in my WordPress Plugin.

```
# Adding React js & style sheet to the Plugin
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_styles_and_script' );
# Call back function of wp admin_enqueue_scripts Hook
function enqueue_styles_and_script($hook){
    # Plugin React CSS
    wp_enqueue_style( 'react-style', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'build/index.css' );
    # Plugin React JS
    wp_enqueue_script( 'react-script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'build/index.js', array('wp-blocks', 'wp-element', 'wp-editor'), '1.0.0', true );
    # Sending data to the Script 
    $data = array( 
      'Name'    => 'Jav',
      'Country' => 'Bangladesh'
    );
   #localizing data to the script.
   wp_localize_script('react-script', 'data', $data);
}
```

Now go to your **react component** and console log data.

```
import React from "react"
function TestComponent() {
    // Check your browser console ***
    console.log(data);
    // 
    return (
        <div className="test">
            <h1>Bismillah, In the name of Allah. Most Mercifully and Gracious.</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
export default TestComponent
```