# Create a react page accessible at a specific URL on Wordpress

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

I'm building a WordPress plugin that creates an admin menu and a public page accessible at a specific URL lets say [www.mywordpress.com/invite-only](http://www.mywordpress.com/invite-only)

In the root directory, I have wp-react-kickoff.php file like this

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Batmobile Design
 * Author: Batman
 * Author URI: 
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Description: WordPress React KickOff.
 * Text-Domain: wp-react-kickoff
 */

if( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) : exit(); endif; // No direct access allowed.

/**
* Define Plugins Contants
*/
define ( 'WPRK_PATH', trailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) );
define ( 'WPRK_URL', trailingslashit( plugins_url( '/', __FILE__ ) ) );

/**
 * Loading Necessary Scripts
 */
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'sd_scripts' );
function sd_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-react-kickoff', WPRK_URL . 'dist/bundle.js', [ 'jquery', 'wp-element' ], wp_rand(), true );
    wp_localize_script( 'wp-react-kickoff', 'appLocalizer', [
        'apiUrl' => home_url( '/wp-json' ),
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' ),
    ] );
}

require_once WPRK_PATH . 'classes/class-create-admin-menu.php';
require_once WPRK_PATH . 'classes/class-create-settings-routes.php';
require_once WPRK_PATH . 'classes/class-public-page.php';
```

Then I have created a folder called classes where I have

```
class-create-admin-menu.php, 
class-create-settings-routes.php, 
class-public-page.php, 
wprk-public-page-template.php.
```

Code to create admin page looks like this

```
<?php
/**
 * This file will create admin menu page.
 */

class WPRK_Create_Admin_Page {

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', [ $this, 'create_admin_menu' ] );
    }

    public function create_admin_menu() {
        $capability = 'manage_options';
        $slug = 'wprk-settings';

        add_menu_page(
            __( 'WP React KickOff', 'wp-react-kickoff' ),
            __( 'WP React KickOff', 'wp-react-kickoff' ),
            $capability,
            $slug,
            [ $this, 'menu_page_template' ],
            'dashicons-buddicons-replies'
        );
    }

    public function menu_page_template() {
        echo '<div class="wrap"><div id="wprk-admin-app"></div></div>';
    }

}
new WPRK_Create_Admin_Page();
```

class-create-settings-routes.php looks like this

```
<?php
/**
 * This file will create Custom Rest API End Points.
 */
class WP_React_Settings_Rest_Route {

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'rest_api_init', [ $this, 'create_rest_routes' ] );
    }

    public function create_rest_routes() {
        register_rest_route( 'wprk/v1', '/settings', [
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => [ $this, 'get_settings' ],
            'permission_callback' => [ $this, 'get_settings_permission' ]
        ] );
        register_rest_route( 'wprk/v1', '/settings', [
            'methods' => 'POST',
            'callback' => [ $this, 'save_settings' ],
            'permission_callback' => [ $this, 'save_settings_permission' ]
        ] );
    }

    public function get_settings() {
        $firstname = get_option( 'wprk_settings_firstname' );
        $lastname  = get_option( 'wprk_settings_lastname' );
        $email     = get_option( 'wprk_settings_email' );
        $response = [
            'firstname' => $firstname,
            'lastname'  => $lastname,
            'email'     => $email
        ];

        return rest_ensure_response( $response );
    }

    public function get_settings_permission() {
        return true;
    }

    public function save_settings( $req ) {
        $firstname = sanitize_text_field( $req['firstname'] );
        $lastname  = sanitize_text_field( $req['lastname'] );
        $email     = sanitize_text_field( $req['email'] );
        update_option( 'wprk_settings_firstname', $firstname );
        update_option( 'wprk_settings_lastname', $lastname );
        update_option( 'wprk_settings_email', $email );
        return rest_ensure_response( 'success' );
    }

    public function save_settings_permission() {
        return current_user_can( 'publish_posts' );
    }
}
new WP_React_Settings_Rest_Route();
```

The code specific to create Public page looks like this

```
function wprk_create_public_page() {
    $page = [
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_title' => 'WP React KickOff Public Page',
        'post_content' => 'asasasas',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1,
    ];
    $page_id = wp_insert_post( $page );
    update_post_meta( $page_id, '_wp_page_template', 'wprk-public-page-template.php' );
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'wprk_create_public_page' );
```

And In the ReactFolder, I have App.js, both Settings (This is for admin menu, it is working properly) and Public Page rendered like this

```
import React from 'react';
import PublicPage from './components/PublicPage';
import Settings from './components/Settings';

function App() {
    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <Settings />
            <PublicPage />
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
export default App;
```

And for testing, let the Public page, look like this

```
import axios from 'axios';

const apiUrl = appLocalizer.apiUrl;
const nonce = appLocalizer.nonce;



import React from 'react';

function PublicPage(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>hello world asasa</h1>
        </div>
    );
}

export default PublicPage;
```

Currently, both the admin page and public page is coming one below the other. I want the Public page to come at a specific URL that users can visit and not just the admins.

[image]

Comment: where is the code to create the admin page?

Comment: Added those codes

Comment: and you want this page to show on the front end? im not sure im understanding what the problem is

Comment: Yes. Right now it is coming below admin settings page. instead, I want it to be a public facing page..... think what if one of the post frontend is controlled by this react app.

Comment: do you need to have the user logged in to view and make changes?

Comment: No. This page is publicly accessible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251344/discussion-between-newbie-developer-and-moishy).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a function to create a page and insert it into database each time you call it.
Instead, create two pages in wp-admin:

1. A user-accesible page
2. An admin page

Give them slug names, in root of your theme directory create templates for these pages. Like, if the admin page has slug react-admin, create a file page-react-admin.php, put the code for the page in there, do it for both pages.
Then you can either restrict the admin page via wp-admin, or, use construction like this:

```
if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    //the actual code for the page goes there
}
else {
   //display a message that you need to log in 
}
```

Check the [WordPress guidelines](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/) for developing themes.

Comment: i'm quite new to programming. Could you please explain with code.